# Random number generation function not work properly

Tags: c#

I need little help in this program. I am generating a random character with the interval of one second in this program when I first run the program from the start button it works fine and give me correct output but when I click on the reset button and run the program again from the start button random function not work properly.

For Example if I add 4 characters (qwer) it gives me 4 random number (ewqr) when I run the program first time but when I press the reset button and again enter the 4 character(qwer) and press the start buttin ot gives me only 2 number means second time funtion run only two times instead 4 times.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private string str = "";
    int sRandom;
    int checkLength;
    // int checkLength;
    Timer mTimer = new Timer();
    Random mRandom = new Random();
    char[] chars;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void startbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            str = richTextBox1.Text;

        if (richTextBox1.Text != "")
        {
            chars = str.ToCharArray();
            InitializeTimer();
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Some text", "please enter the key you want to practise",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }

    private void resetbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Clear();
        richTextBox2.Clear();
        str = "";
        sRandom = 0;
        checkLength = 0;
    }

    private void InitializeTimer()
    {
        mTimer.Interval = 1000;
        mTimer.Enabled = true;
        mTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkLength <= chars.Length - 1)
        {

            sRandom = mRandom.Next(chars.Length);
            richTextBox2.Text = chars[sRandom].ToString() + checkLength;

            checkLength++;
        }

        else
        {
            mTimer.Enabled = false;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Each time you call `InitializeTimer()`, you add a new handler to the `Tick` event. Add the handler in the constructor and never again. If this Form is opened multiple times, remove the handler in the `FormClosed` event and also dispose of the Timer.

Comment: As a general hint:  You have named your Buttons in such a way that we can't tell which button does what. So when you talk about "Reset Button" we don't know if this is Button1, 2, or 3 in your code!   You should also only include the code necessary to show the problem.  Empty event methods etc. should be removed.

Comment: sorry my mistake right now using only 2 button button 1 and 3 button is for start and button 3 for reset